# How to bulk update a field in elasticsearch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

```
def update(index):
    index = "twitter"
    list = ['0oPwSm4BxbPrifDrF7C1', 'r4MOWm4BxbPrifDrjbgR', 'y4NbWm4BxbPrifDrLLhh']
    data  = []
    for i in list:
        d = { "update" : {"_id" : i, "_index" : index, "retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
        e = { "doc" : {"answer_1" : "test"} }
        data.append(json.dumps(d))
        data.append(json.dumps(e))
    v = "\n".join(data)
    response = requests.post('https://url/_bulk', headers='application/x-ndjson', 
    data=json.loads(v)
```

I want to bulk update the answer field for different documents. Unable to send request in a proper format i guess.

Comment: have a look here https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk data set should be like this,

```
{'index': ''}\n
{'your': 'data'}\n
{'index': ''}\n
{'other': 'data'}\n
```

**NB:** the new-lines, even on the last row.

Your existing data seems OK to me,

```
{"update": {"_id": "0oPwSm4BxbPrifDrF7C1", "retry_on_conflict": 3, "_index": "twitter"}}
{"doc": {"answer_1": "test"}}
{"update": {"_id": "r4MOWm4BxbPrifDrjbgR", "retry_on_conflict": 3, "_index": "twitter"}}
{"doc": {"answer_1": "test"}}
{"update": {"_id": "y4NbWm4BxbPrifDrLLhh", "retry_on_conflict": 3, "_index": "twitter"}}
{"doc": {"answer_1": "test"}}
```

You have got a syntax error on the `request.post()` where you missed ending parenthesis `)` and need to send `v` directly without using extra `json.loads(v)`

```
response = requests.post('https://url/_bulk', 
                         data=v,
                         headers={'content-type':'application/json', 
                         'charset':'UTF-8'})
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem

```
data=json.loads(v)
```

'v' does not contain a parsable json string, it contains multiple JSON documents seperated by new lines. Try sending v directly without parsing.